# What do the dots mean in HN.CO.CH3 connected to the second carbon of N- Acetylglucosamine? And what do the N and acetyl indicate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

[image]

What do the dots mean in HN.CO.CH3 connected to the second carbon of N- Acetylglucosamine? And what do the N and acetyl indicate?

Comment: What is glucosamine? What is an acetyl? The acetyl is connected to the amine at the nitrogen atom, hence *N*-acetyl. These "dots" (they look more like blobs to me) are just a simple covalent bond. *Why* they look like blobs I have no idea.

Comment: These don't look like dots to me, more like en-dashes used for denoting chemical bonds (e.g. $\ce{HN-CO-CH3}$). Probably they were chosen short by the typography in order to fit an entire structure on the page. *N-* indicate the substituent on the *nitrogen*, and the task of finding what is *acetyl* is I leave to you:)

Comment: They look more like dashs to me, a dash is a common symbol for a single bond

Answer (score 6):

These are not dots. They actually are single bonds though I do not know why they are printed that way. As such, they should be represented by a half-long dash (called EN DASH in Unicode).

In the name *N*-acetylglucosamine, acetyl means that a hydrogen atom has been replaced an acetyl group (i.e. –CO–CH3) and that the replacement occurred on the nitrogen (aka "N") atom.

Overall, it means something like: "consider glucosamine but replace one hydrogen on the nitrogen atom by an acetyl group". This is the standard "substitutive naming" defined by the IUPAC.